# How do I use OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I have a XAMPP localhost site running on my computer using 127.0.0.1 but I was wondering that because OpenSSL is included how do I use it for other purpose like for my emails.

I was wondering is there a tutorials for using it on Windows XP SP3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, explain specifically what you mean by other purposes.  Do you have a webmail, IMAP or POP3 or other server you want to use your SSL certificate for?  I honestly don't see a reason to bother with it at all if your servers are only accessible to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @mootinator well I am 12 years old so no POP3 server but I want to atach it to my emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send encrypted e-mail what you need to do depends on what e-mail client you're using.  If you're using gmail, for instance, there are browser plugins available which enable S/MIME support.

Alternately, you *could* use the [smime](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) command line tool to encrypt and decrypt the messages.  You will need a public key from each recipient you want to send encrypted messages to.

If you just want to encrypt messages using a shared key (both you and the recipient know the password) as opposed to using public/private keys, you'd probably have an easier time using something like [GPG](http://www.madboa.com/geek/gpg-quickstart/)

Comment: I mean how do I use openssl on a Win

Comment: Your question is really probably a better fit for http://www.superuser.com (or *maybe* serverfault).